# Set folder permissions for HomeGroup

Tags: powershell, folder-permissions

I found the following which seems to work for what it is, but I need 2 things changed, and can't figure it out.

```
$acl = Get-Acl D:\New
$permission = "Everyone","Read","Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl D:\New
```

1. I need to be able to give "HomeGroup" permission, *not* "Everyone".
2. I need this to recurse all folders.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You need to change the identity from `"Everyone"` to `"$env:COMPUTERNAME\HomeGroup"` and set the appropriate [inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.inheritanceflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [propagation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.propagationflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) flags.

```
$identity    = "$env:COMPUTERNAME\HomeGroup"
$accessRight = 'Read'
$inheritance = 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit'
$propagation = 'None'
$type        = 'Allow'

$accessRule = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule (
                $identity, $accessRight, $inheritance, $propagation, $type
              )
```

Comment: Thx, but it's not working. Getting... Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."

Comment: Check the name of the group. Also try just the group name (without the hostname).